# How to measure distance between a polygon layer and a line layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3

I have a polygon dataset that contains a handful of businesses. I also have an OSM roads line dataset. I am looking for the tool in QGIS that allows me to measure the distance from the polygon (either centroid or border is fine) to the nearest roads line segment. I tried the distance matrix tool, but it only allows for point layers to be used. I also tried the distance to nearest hub tools to no avail.